# large aggregation queries optimization

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table events with columns
`user_id, event_type, date`. I need to create a table which aggregates it in the following way

```
select user_id, event_type, count(*)
group by user_id, event_type where date >= (30 days ago) and date <= today
```

However events table is fairly large with more than billions of rows each day. Currently, I am aggregating it on a daily basis and it takes about an hour to compute one day's aggregation. However, it is a huge headache if I need to backfill the data which means I need to recompute last 30 days aggregation one by one and it's taking forever. Anyway this can be simplified?

Comment: FROM clause is lost. WHERE clause must be placed before GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Create index on date column, that would improve the performace

Comment: You have tagged the question with both MySQL and Presto which are 2 vastly different technologies. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I am using presto @GuruStron

Comment: How long does it take to just run such query without aggregating by day?

Answer (score 2):

> Anyway this can be simplified?

Create according index. Test which index is more safe on your system and real data:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table (user_id, event_type, `date`);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON table (`date`, user_id, event_type);
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zlhvcWEy)

Pay attention - when both indices are present the server selects `idx2`. But the index `idx1` may be preferred nevertheless - it does not use temporary on-disk rowset rather than `idx2`. In practice you'd compare the execution time on your real dataset and select/create only one of these indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create indexes in order to increase the performance as @Akina described.

But you could also cache your results by storing the results for each day for each user in the latest 30 days. So, the next day a cron job could remove the no longer interesting old aggregations and upon each day, you could either compute the given day's aggregation and upon request add the older 29 days' results, or, if that takes too much time, you could have a cron job running on each hour to adjust the given day's aggregation based on the events of the latest hour (so at 1 AM you aggregate the first hour for the users, at 2 AM you aggregate the second and add it to the results so far and so on).

This way you will greatly reduce the difficulty you need to cope with, because you reuse the results of earlier days.